# Lax pairs and Nonlinear Schrodinger Equation's components

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, integrable-systems, lax-pair

**Briefly:** I have two Lax pairs in matrix form and using compatibility condition I have found a nonlinear partial differential equation system. I have searched this system very much seems the nonlinear Schrodinger Equation system ([in wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nonlinear_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#/Solving_the_equation)) but I am stuck how to derive it nonlinear Schrodinger eq. from these two nonlinear pde, I have tried some transformations but could not do it.

**Work:**
Lax Pairs
$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
    -\lambda & u\\
    v & \lambda \\ 
\end{bmatrix}\quad,\quad T=\begin{bmatrix}
   -\lambda^2+\frac12uv ,&\lambda u-\frac12u_x \\ \lambda v+\frac12v_x & \lambda^2 -\frac12uv \\
\end{bmatrix}\tag1$$

Compatibility condition is $$D_tX-D_xT+[X,T]=0$$ where $$[X,T]=XT-TX$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & u_t+\frac12u_{xx}-u^2v\\
    v_t-\frac12v_{xx}+uv^2 & 0\\ 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

so both have to be zero as following

$$u_t+\frac12u_{xx}-u^2v=0\\
v_t-\frac12v_{xx}+uv^2=0\tag2$$

[as I cited above](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Nonlinear_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#/Solving_the_equation)

suggested transformations are $u=\pm v^*$ but what does it mean? and my system $(2)$ has no $i$ coefficients. So I am stuck here **how to derive nonlinear Schrodinger equation** namely $$i\Phi_t+\Phi_{xx}+\sigma \Phi^2\Phi^*=0$$ from this system? I am sure about it because it is an exercise problem and I cannot figure it out.